# Avoid Bus error: 10 during test cases

Tags: c

I'm attempting to remove duplicate characters from a string without using any additional buffer. The code works when I declare a single variable like this

```
char s[] = "aaabbb";
```

but not when I'm attempting to loop through a few test cases.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Design an algorithm and write code to remove the duplicate characters in a string
without using any additional buffer. NOTE: One or two additional variables are fine.
An extra copy of the array is not. */

void removeDuplicates(char s[]) {
    // attempts to modify array in place without extra buffer
}

int main() {
    char *s[4] = {"aaaa", "abcd", "ababab", "aaabbb"};

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        removeDuplicates(s[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This returns `Bus error: 10` because it's attempting to modify the string literal `"aaaa"` but I'm not sure how to overcome this while maintaining a nice setup for the test cases.

Comment: Just strcpy each one in turn into a [128] buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `s[i]` are pointing to string literals, you need a 2-dimensinal `char` array like this:

```
char s[][7] = {"aaaa", "abcd", "ababab", "aaabbb"}
```

Also note that for a string of length `n` you need at least `n+1` spaces because of the `'\0'-termination.`"aaabbb"` has length 6, so it need at least 7 spaces.

Then you can do

```
int main() {
    char s[][7] = {"aaaa", "abcd", "ababab", "aaabbb"};

    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof s / sizeof s[0]; i++) {
        removeDuplicates(s[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```